# How to debug BLE HID Connection (STM32WB55)

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, debugging, bluetooth-low-energy, hid

I'm working on implementing a BLE HID keyboard using an STM32WB55 (the nucleo board).  The BLE HID example they provide is a mouse, where you press a button on the nucleo and input stuff into a menu via CLI, and it presses keys or changes pointer location.  I've successfully modified it to skip the menu and press/release the mouse button when I press/release the nucleo switch.  This gave me some confidence that I understand the way that the code is working.

Now that I'm trying to port from a mouse to a keyboard, I'm encountering some problems.  I made a new HID report descriptor (copied one from the web and went through it to understand it), and updated my code to put in keypresses.  In the debugger, I can see the memory locations that I would expect be filled with my new keypress data as I step through, but nothing shows on the PC when I would expect a keypress to show up.

The biggest problem is that I don't know how to debug this well.  I can see my device as an HID device, but beyond that, I can't see the HID report map/descriptor, so it's hard to tell what's going on.  Any tips on how I can debug this?  Is there some piece of software or hardware that would allow me to see what the PC sees?

Thanks!